# The `g` suffix for some GnuWin32 utils

Tags: gnuwin32

For these commands there are both a `g`-suffix version and a plain version:

```
gdate.exe
gecho.exe
ginstall.exe
gln.exe
gmkdir.exe
grmdir.exe
gsort.exe
```

I can't find the difference.

Edit
Someone is interested to this: OS Win7 Pro, [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net)  coreutils 5.3.

To be clear, `g` is the marketing suffix accompanying software released under GNU licensing terms (like `k` for KDE desktop apps). Here I'd like to know why only these commands (in coreutils) are suffixed and what is the difference with the others in the same directory without the suffix.

Comment: I assume you are using windows? Where are you getting these names from? Are they perhaps links?

Comment: @terdon: GnuWin= "ports of tools with a GNU or similar open source license, to modern MS-Windows" (gnuwin32.sourceforge.net). Download coreutils and find the binaries here `coreutils-5.3.0-bin\bin`.

Comment: I know, I am pointing out the kind of details you should include in your question, your OS, the source you have downloaded things from etc.

Comment: @terdon: I did but my question is not connected with my OS version and the website/description for gnuwin32 should be in the tag summary.

Comment: My apologies, I had misunderstood the sitiation. I thought you had downloaded both `gdate.exe` _and_ `date.exe` from the GNU tools site so I was asking where you got them so I could easily go and have a look to see if I could figure out what was wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `g` [**prefix**](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+suffix) here means that the tool is from GnuWin32 as opposed to the native Windows command of the same name. For example, `mkdir` and `echo` are builtin commands in the `cmd.exe` shell, and `find.exe` is part of Windows and does a completely different thing from the coreutils `find` (it is actually more similar to `grep`). Therefore, the prefix is needed to allow accessing both native and GnuWin32 commands at the same time.

Comment: Clear, while I don't see a built-in `ln` and `install`, while very common, isn't built-in either.